# Vm end point in mule pros and cons

Tags: mule

I want to use VM endpoints for achieving parallel processing in mule flows. Being a beginner with mule, I am not quite sure about the implications of doing so. I read about private flows in mule 3 , but not sure, if I can replace vm endpoints with private flows in this case and if at all there would be any advantage I can get with that. Can someone, please let me know about the pros and cons of using VM . Here is the example I wanted to use for parallel processing.

```
<flow name="forkAndJoinFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="81" path="lowestprice" />
    <not-filter>
        <wildcard-filter pattern="*favicon*" />
    </not-filter>
    <request-reply>
        <all>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="shop1"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="shop2"/>
        </all>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="response">
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="2" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <collection-aggregator />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>
    <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="java.util.Collections.min(payload)" />
    <object-to-string-transformer/>
    <logger level="WARN" message="#[string:Lowest price: #[payload]]" />
</flow>

<flow name="shop1Flow">

    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="shop1"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="SHOP1 Flow..." />
    <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="new java.lang.Double(1000.0 * Math.random()).intValue()" />
    <logger level="WARN" message="#[string:Price from shop 1: #[payload]]" />
</flow>

<flow name="shop2Flow">

    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="shop2" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="SHOP2 Flow..." />
    <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="new java.lang.Double(1000.0 * Math.random()).intValue()" />
    <logger level="WARN" message="#[string:Price from shop 2: #[payload]]" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vm:endpoints` are `one-way` and `asynchronous`, that means you'll not receive a response back from them.

`Private flows` can be `synchronous` as well as `asynchronous`, means they can return a response also if the `exchange-pattern` is `request-response`.

Also, in `private flow` you get all `variables` and `headers` etc versus when you push your message in `vm` or any other `JMS`, `variables` and `inbound properties` are **not** propagated and `outbound properties` of the caller flow becomes `inbound` in called flow

Comment: But can private flows be used in scenarios like parallel processing, where u would actually want two or more flows to run in parallel and then wait for them to complete before building the response>

Comment: if you want them to complete before proceeding further, that means you want synchronous private flows. In case of vm, message will be pushed to vm and current thread processing will move forward

Answer (score 0):

`Private flows` can be used as a replacement for your `VM`.

As explained `private flows`  can be `Synchronus` or `Asynchronous` based on the `processingStrategy` of the flow.

I case you use a private flow in asynchronous  way to acheive parallel processing, then make sure that response is posted back onto the response VM at the end of each of the private flows.

I have implemented the fork-join pattern of parallel processing using sub-flows as well. Try this.

```
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="1" />
    <all enableCorrelation="IF_NOT_SET">
        <async>
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="1" />
            <flow-ref name="parallel-flow1"></flow-ref>
        </async>
        <async>
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE"  value="2" />
            <flow-ref name="parallel-flow2"></flow-ref>
        </async>
    </all>
```

And the sub-flows as follows.

```
    <sub-flow name="parallel-flow1">    
        ....
        ....
        <flow-ref name="join-flow" />       
    </sub-flow>

    <sub-flow name="parallel-flow2">    
        ....
        ....
        <flow-ref name="join-flow" />       
    </sub-flow>

    <sub-flow name="join-flow">
        <collection-aggregator  timeout="10000"   failOnTimeout="true"  />          
        <combine-collections-transformer />
        ....
        ....
    </sub-flow>
```

You can try this with private flows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This ain't working for me, am able to execute the flows in parallel, but mainflow is not waiting for the join-flow to complete. Can you please show me how to do this using a HTTP request-response inbound enpoint

Comment: that qualifies for separate question. Please close this one and open another @user2963582